# Enable a disabled Cancel button when clicking on enabled Edit button vueJS and add a Save button additionally

Tags: vue.js, button, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I am using VUEJS for for FrontEnd, am new to vuejs. Am using element component UI. I have the Edit button which is enabled and Cancel button which is disabled on the screen and **when i want to Edit i will click on Edit button and then the disabled Cancel button should get enabled and also the Save button should be added beside it**.

I want this scenario, can anyone please help.

Thanks in Advance

Tried few fixes and failed

Comment: Sure we can help. Could you add the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help you with you're code, but basically you can do it like this :

```
<template>
  <button @click="startEdition">Edit</button>
  <button :disabled="!editMode" @click="cancelEdition">Cancel</button>
  <button v-show="editMode">Save</button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        editMode: false,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      startEdition() {
        this.editMode = true;
      },
      cancelEdition() {
        this.editMode = false;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```